# How to convert quaternion to matrix4 form of real number, what`s the principle?

Tags: matrix, quaternions

Suppose `Quaternion q=a+bi+cj+dk`, the matrix4 of q is:

```
| a -b  d -c|
| b  a -c -d|
|-d  c  a -b|
| c  d  b  a|
```

Where does this matrix come from?

Answer (score 2):

Your question could use a little more clarification.  However, this matrix seems to be expressing the [rules of quaternion multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Multiplication_of_basis_elements).  Consider two complex numbers **c<sub>1</sub> = a<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>1</sub>i** and **c<sub>2</sub> = a<sub>2</sub> + b<sub>2</sub>i**.  If you multiply them, you get **c<sub>3</sub> = c<sub>1</sub>c<sub>2</sub> = (a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>-b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>) + (a<sub>2</sub>b<sub>1</sub>+a<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>)i**, because you need to cross multiply the real parts and the imaginary parts.  You could encode this in matrix/vector form:

```
| a1 -b1 | * |a2| = |a1a2-b1b2|
| b1  a1 |   |b2|   |a2b1+a1b2|
```

The quaternion rules are an extension of the complex.  The same idea holds.